# Will document.elementFromPoint forces layout / reflow?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to use elementFromPoint to detect if the target element is truly visible to a user which not covered by some other elements e.g. dialogs.

In this experiment, 500 evenly distributed sample points are chosen from the surface of target element. However, I run into some perf issues related to elementFromPoint, specially bad during scrolling the page. From the Chrome Performance tab, it turns out that the most of total time are spending in rendering, that is 207.2ms rendering contributing to 216.31ms total time [elementFromPoint summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LO59.png).

Will document.elementFromPoint forces layout/reflow?

It is not very clear from the elementFromPoint definition:

"The elementFromPoint(x, y) method must follow these steps:

If either argument is negative, x is greater than the viewport width excluding the size of a rendered scroll bar (if any), or y is greater than the viewport height excluding the size of a rendered scroll bar (if any), or there is no viewport associated with the document, return null and terminate these steps.

If there is a layout box in the viewport that would be a target for hit testing at coordinates x,y, when applying the transforms that apply to the descendants of the viewport, return the associated element and terminate these steps.

If the document has a root element, return the root element and terminate these steps.
Return null."

Here is a sample code to test the performance of document.elementFromPoint:

```
    var elementFromPointPerf = function(x, y){
      var t0 = performance.now();
      for(let i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
        let test = document.elementFromPoint(
           Math.random() * x,
           Math.random() * y,
         );
      }
      var t1 = performance.now();
      console.log(
         'Call to elementFromPoint took ' +
           ((t1 - t0)/100000) +     ' milliseconds.',
      );
    };
```

The result varies, depending on the complexity of a page.

Comment: Not at all clear what your specific problem is. Calling `elementFromPoint()` does nothing to change the dom in any way and would not cause reflow unless you do something with the element it returns

Comment: @charlietfl I'm pretty sure that it forces a reflow, as it needs to *observe* the current rendering positions of the dom elements. (Of course a reflow only will happen if something in the DOM did change since last time, but that can be something as trivial as a scroll position).

Comment: @Weiran How are you using `elementFromPoint` so that it causes performance issues? Yes, it's a slow method, you shouldn't call it too often. Can you post a [mcve] that exhbits the problems?